# Aspose.Tasks. Microsoft Project. Get the resource usage by day

Tags: c#, .net, ms-project, aspose

Im trying to get a resource usage of specific resource in specific day.
I tryed to use `Resource.TimeScaleData` but it always returns `0` items.

While in debug mode, the `Resource.TimephasedData` ArrayList has 6118 items.

Maybe, there is a sample code for getting resource usage?
Can someone direct me, how to approach these?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set tsv = ActiveProject.Resources("your resource").TimeScaleData(#6/6/2013#, #6/6/2013#)
amt = tsv(1)
```

This will give you the amount of *forecast* work for the resource for the given day, expressed in minutes. If you want baseline work, you'll need to add the third argument (e.g. pjResourceTimescaledBaselineWork).